pyinstaller in poetry - `pyi_rth_pkgres` error
I am trying to compile my application on the poetry environment where I am building the package.
Here is the spec file. This same spec file compiles fine via GitHub actions but fails on my poetry environment.
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

datas = []
datas += copy_metadata('pkg', recursive = True)

a = Analysis(
    ['app.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='pkg',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)

When I run the command pyinstaller --clean app.spec  , it gives me this warning which makes me think that pyinstaller is not able to fine some dependencies in the virtual environment.
219 WARNING: Assuming this is not an Anaconda environment or an additional venv/pipenv/... 
environment manager is being used on top, because the conda-meta folder
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\venv\conda-meta does not exist.

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions to fix this. Below is the ImportError I get in the window of the compiled executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgrespy", line 158, in <module>
File "PyInstaller \hooks \rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py" line 36, in _pyi_rthook
File "PyInstaller\loader \pyimode2_importers .py", line 419, in exec _module
File "pkg _resources\__init__py", line 63, in <module>
File "PyInstaller \loader \pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec _module
File "plistlib.py", line 70, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader \pyimode2_importers py", line 419, in exec_ module
File "xmI \parsers \expat.py" line 4, in <module>
[ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pyexpat: The specified module could not be found.
[22988] Failed to execute script "pyi rth_pkgres" due to unhandled exception!

I included setuptools  in my poetry dependencies as per a stack overflow suggestion, but didn't help.

What's the current version of your PyInstaller? Try reinstalling it. By the way, if you are using anaconda, it won't be easy to solve the problem. I suggest using the official clean Python with PyInstaller.

Thanks for the tips! I'm using 6.7.0. I tried re-installing the entire poetry environment but some error. Yeah, I think the conda environment is creating some issue here. I'll need some time to switch to the official python. Will update when I do so.
